# C# Pull a webpage with HTTPWebRequest and execute the javascript from the site

Tags: c#, javascript, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

is there a way to fetch a webpage with HTTPWebRequest and then execute all the javascriptcode that was on the page along with ajax calls and save the result to a string?

I want to parse a website where some images are generated via js code and the images aren't on the webpage before the js script has run.

Now I searched the web for a solution to this but all I found were answers like this isn't possible, use the webbrowser instead which is not an option for me.

Greetings

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using the WebBrowser class is not an option?

Comment: http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/ elaboration on what alexn is suggesting.  I can't tell from your Q if you can't use *the* `WebBrowser` object if you can't use *a* web browser.

Comment: WebBrowser is slow and sometimes buggy, speed matters to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with the C++ http system which gives you a lot of control over the pieces of data that are receievd, but I guess that's not really an answer so...

Why not try putting [webkit into your app](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/docs/), and running off the events from it. It has several events that can notify you when downloads are started and finished.

Comment: I think the quick and easy way to do this is the WebBrowser control, the best one for him is using that .NET WebKit wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research just because I thought it was interesting. I found something called Phantom.js which looks like it does what you need. Check it out:
http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Interesting project, but it appears to be more freestanding and not for use in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed isn't possible, as I found out while trying to meet a much-required demand. The Javascript will execute, but the Ajax calls won't be made.

The solution I settled for was to get all the data the Ajax calls would have synchronously, through the code-behind file(C# code), and to assign code-behind variables to Javascript variables, using script tags, and let Javascript do its work(building dynamic elements etc.)

Comment: and what did you use to execute the javascript without the ajax calls?

Comment: Sync Javascript executes anyway in any web request. It's only with async code(ajax calls, callbacks) that it fails.
To answer the question: I used the `WebRequest` class in ASP.NET.