# Code cannot find a line on a website

Tags: url, line

I've been trying to find a line and print it out on this website: http://www.easports.com/player-hub/360/Its+McDoom

Right now it prints out everything on the website, but I cannot find the line I am looking for. I am trying to print out "H2h Skill Points: 1053", but I cannot find anything like that in the console.

I only really want it to print that 1 line, not the whole thing, but I can't even find it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;



public class ElectronicArtsStatHub {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
            URL oracle = new URL("http://www.easports.com/player-hub/360/Its+McDoom");
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the information your trying to find isn't actually in the data you are currently outputting.

When you open the page in your browser you get the main page elements but then your browser then runs some Javascript code which presumably uses AJAX to get the stats and fill in the table.

The URLConnection receives the same data that your browser initially does and does not execute the Javascript so if you check your output that data your looking for isn't actually there at all.

Possible solutions include finding a different source for this data or executing the Javascript in Java possibly by using [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

There may be some helpful infomation on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423209/c-sharp-pull-a-webpage-with-httpwebrequest-and-execute-the-javascript-from-the-s)

Comment: Right, I'll take a look at that HTMLUnit, thnx.