# Getting a dynamic web page source in C #

Tags: c#, web

How can I download a dynamic web page source using C #? More specifically, for example, I have a page http://example.com. Downloading the source, but because of AJAX, which adds a few lines to the source, after collection, I do not get what I want. Does anyone know how to "refresh" the source, or if at all there is a way to achieve something like this? Your existing "static" code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData("http://example.com" + address);
string pageHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pageData);
Console.WriteLine(pageHtml);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Regards.

Comment: Why do I have a hunch this is for nefarious data-mining purposes? :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Pull a webpage with HTTPWebRequest and execute the javascript from the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423209/c-sharp-pull-a-webpage-with-httpwebrequest-and-execute-the-javascript-from-the-s)

Comment: You'll need to use a client that executes JavaScript.  A simple `WebClient` object doesn't do this.  A `WebBrowser` object might.

Comment: @Moo Juice - No. I'm just a beginner in C # and I wanted to create a simple application that when you type a word in German for example, give me the equivalent in English. These are just my exercises for web use. Although I'm not sure if I could do something like that, because from what I've read the usual Google Translate API is paid

Comment: The Bing Translator API is free to an extent: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Form with WebBrowser component. Let's say you name it    `browser`

```
private void PrepareDocument()
{
   browser.Navigate("http://somewebsite.com");
   var timer = new Timer(1000);
   timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
   timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   //parse the document, find the data that should be loaded after ajax call
   if(browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && 
      browser.Document.GetElementById("ajax-divId") != null)
   {
      timer.Enabled=false;
      ProceedOnDocument();
   }
}

private void ProceedOnDocument()
{
   //your code here
}
```